# Why can a Java object act like a lock and a condition queue?

Tags: java, types, concurrency, synchronization, duck-typing

From Java Concurrency in Pactice

> **Every Java object can implicitly act as a lock** for purposes of synchronization; these built-in locks are called intrinsic locks or
>   monitor locks.

What does "Every Java object can implicitly act as a lock" mean?

Does it mean that the class of every Java object implements the `Lock` interface as following?

```
public interface Lock {    
    void lock();
    void lockInterruptibly() throws InterruptedException;
    boolean tryLock();
    boolean tryLock(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException;
    void unlock();
    Condition newCondition();    
}
```

Does it mean that the class of every Java object provides some method that make the object act like a lock, in the sense of duck typing?

> Just as  each Java object can act as a lock, **each object can also
>   act as a condition queue**, and the wait, notify, and notifyAll
>   methods in Object constitute the API for intrinsic condition queues.

What does "each object can also act as a condition queue" mean?

Does it mean that the class of each Java object

- implements some "condition queue" interface, or
- provides some methods that make the object act like a condition queue in the sense of duck typing?

Thanks.

Comment: "Does it mean that the class of every Java object implements the Lock interface as following?" No, it means any object can be used as the expression in `synchronized (expression) { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks. What type of object does `synchronized` expect in the parentheses?

Comment: [Any reference type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19). That's the point.

Comment: "Does ["each object can also act as a condition queue"] mean that the class of each Java object" no, like it says, "the wait, notify, and notifyAll methods in Object constitute the API for intrinsic condition queues." These are methods that you'll find in [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)'s Javadoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not mean that every class implements the `Lock` interface (indeed, that interface was created a decade or more after the introduction of the idea that every object has an *implicit monitor* which has been around practically since the introduction of Java).

It only means that every object has an implicit monitor that allows it to be used as a simple mutex, as follows:

```
synchronized (someObject) {
  // this region is protected from concurrent execution by other threads
  // locking on the same object
}
```

It can also be used in more sophisticated monitor use cases such as `wait()` and `notify()`, which is what allows it to act as a kind of condition variable (which is probably another name for *condition variable*?).

The benefits and downsides of this decision are somewhat hotly debated: while it does mean you don't need separate mutex or condition variable objects, it places a burden on the implementation since *any* object can be used in this way, even though probably a vanishingly small fraction of objects ever are. There are lots of implementation tricks being used to reduce this cost.

Beginning with Java 5, there are now many explicit synchronization primitives offered by the JDK, including the various `Lock` implementations.